# Filter the data contains a particular string

Tags: r

I wish to filter those of my data that contains a particular string. Let's assume this is my data set

```
#dst

 first    second 
  24       Sienna,Zoe,Dylan
  32       Amber,John,Noah,Sienna
  72       Daniel,Mike,Zoe
```

And I wish to have only data that contains "Zoe". So, I'd like to have this output

```
#output 

first    second
24       Sienna,Zoe,Dylan
72       Daniel,Mike,Zoe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the grep or grepl factions.
If your data frame is named "dst", then this should work:

```
output<-dst[grep("Zoe", dst$second),]
```

Comment: Thanks Dave2e, It worked for me